# Opening react-native-sidebar onPress

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, jsx

o/

I have recently started playing around with react-native and made a couple of smaller test apps.
My latest project is supposed to include a sidebar menu, and i [react-native-sidebar](https://github.com/bringnow/react-native-sidebar). But i seem to be unable to figure out how I'm suppose to open the sidebar - and sadly their doc doesn't provide much information regarding anything.

Code:

```
renderLeftSidebar()
{
   return <Text>LEFT SIDE BAR CONTENT</Text>        
}

renderContent()
{
    return(<Button onPress={___OPEN__SIDEBAR___}><Text>Open Sidebar</Text></Button>)   
}

render() {
    return (
        <Sidebar leftSidebar         = { this.renderLeftSidebar() }
                 open                = 'left'
                 style               = {styles.leftSidebarContainer}>
            { this.renderContent() }
        </Sidebar>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

leftSidebarContainer:
{
    flex: 1,
},
});
```

since i set Sidebar open = 'left' it starts as open, but how do i change it - so it is only open'ed when i press my button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself, i had to set a reference for the sidebar:

```
ref = {(c) => this._leftsidebar = c}
```

and then just call:

```
this._sidebar.open('left')
```